# Slow network on Windows 7 64-bit and Intel 82562V-2 NIC

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm having performance problems with the Intel 82562V-2 NIC on Windows 7 64-bit. I'm getting under 300kb/s when copying files in my network.

I have no problems with other computers. The same NIC was working fine on Windows Vista 32-bit.

I've download and updated the drivers from Intel to the latest version but the problem persists.

Is anyone experiencing this problem? What else can I check?

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the latest driver from intel then you need to change the duplex settings.  It is set to "Auto Negotiation" by changing it to "100 Mbps Full" your performance problem will go away.

For those reading who need to install the latest driver http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx and choose the device you have.

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think of are:

1. Are you using 64-bit drivers for the NIC, as you have mentioned that you are using Windows 7 64-bit.
2. Are you sure your data is not being routed through the *Interwebs*, rather than through the local LAN.

I have had #2 happen to me once or twice with misconfigured multiple subnets in my local LAN.